# WCM API :Can't set File or Image for LibraryFileComponent or LibraryImageComponent

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-portal, ibm-wcm

Today i try to create LibraryImageComponent or LibraryFileComponent on my wcm portal. Code as below :

```
workspace = createWorkspace();
DocumentLibrary documentLib = workspace.getDocumentLibrary(Config.LIBRARY_NAME);
    workspace.setCurrentDocumentLibrary(documentLib);
workspace.login();
try {
    LibraryFileComponent file = workspace.createFileComponent();
    file.setName("FileUploadDemo");
    File f = new File("C:/Users/huyenlt/Desktop/TinVeBIDV/TinVeBIDV/files/94747249_38ba_48fb_b150_7267fd7a1c9aCTR_KTA___GS_UBKT_2018.doc");
    file.setResource("helo",f);
    file.setFile("helo",f);
    workspace.save(file);
}
 catch (Exception e2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? But you shouldn't use both setFile and setResource, only use setResource. First argument of that should be the file name.

Comment: tks, I got this problem. Everything fine now.

Comment: Hi Roberg, are you use ckeditor and kcfinder in websphere portal >?